# knockout components - viewmodel constructor with a callback

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a viewmodel, that has a callback as a parameter to the constructor - call it "onReady", along with other necessary parameters. It cannot be bound to the view (template) until the callback has executed. Is there any way this can work with knockout components? It seems knockout components try to avoid this as "createViewModel" needs to be synchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async work can be done by the viewmodel or the script file, find attached a sample.

```js
// ViewModel object
// Really? callback as a constructor parameter?
function ViewModel(callback){  
  
  // busy message
  this.message=ko.observable("loading");
  
  
  var _this=this;
  callback(function(response){
    _this.message(response);
  });
  
   
  
}

// register the component
ko.components.register('onready', {
    viewModel: function(params) {
        return params.viewModel
    },
    template:
        '<div data-bind="text:message"></div>'
});

// make viewmodel instance
var viewModel=new ViewModel( function(response){
  // start the async work
  window.setTimeout( function(){
       response("ready!");
  },1000);


  }
);




// plain normal ko
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>


<onready params="viewModel:$data"></onready>
```